# Is there a way to see all pages where a list may be displayed or linked as a look up?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column

I've inherited a SharePoint site and I'm trying to clean up numerous lists and libraries (either "retiring" or just plain deleting them).

Does anyone know  of an easy way to find out where lists/libraries/pages are connected to each other either via the look-up columns or as hyperlinks? I would rather avoid trying to go into every page/list/library/site to track down to see where everything is connected.

Please note I do not have access to PowerShell or any server side access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any 3rd party tool like Metalogix or Sharegate etc. to view all the list, libraries and site contents. You can also do a lot of clean up work using these tools.

Comment: Noman,
Thanks for the suggestion.  I may have to get permission and clearance to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead, monitor what is used for a couple of months.

But in these scenarios I always ask:

*What is the benefit of spending weeks cleaning up if we can buy extra diskspace for almost nothing?*

Performance is not much of an issue, as stuff that is not used remains in a bloated Database.

If you can't get in from the server side, you could do it Client-Side with JSOM/REST scripting.
Recursive dive into sites/libraries/fields
and Page content
and WebPart content
and more?

Comment: Danny,
I am a bit of a neat freak, so I loath inheriting a site with lots of lists/libraries and site that are empty with no explanation as to why they exist.  So I need a quick way to track down where those things may be linked in order to remove them.  Monitoring traffic only shows if the link is clicked, not where the link is.  I would use it to also make sure that any retired lists or libraries are not showing up anywhere.  Can you link the script?

Comment: I don't have that script because I used to be a neat freak as well; then my boss made me do the calculations, I calculated it would take me 3 weeks to clean up and the risk a dirty environment would cause harm to the business was 0%. Empty unused sites only take up diskspace.. If you can get your boss to pay then buy the ShareGate stuff... in the end your company will have paid 15K ... if you say you need clearance I guess it will be the US taxpayer who paid for it.. :-)

Comment: Danny, Yes I don't see the need to spend any money either, I was just wondering if there was a quick way of doing it.  Ah well.  I was monitoring items as just a default so stick with that.  Thanks for the help!